# Is it possible to install Ubuntu Phone in old Nokia Smartphones?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I know and still early but I wonder if you can install ubuntu phone (so to speak) in the old nokia smartphones (microsoft). I'm talking about lumia line. I'm a big fan of lumia line and was wondering if you can. Recalling that the lumia and Windows Phone. I saw the Ubuntu Phone can install through the Android.

Comment: Very difficult - in two words: drivers issues (com between the software and the hardware) as they were designed only for windows and need to create suitable ones for Ubuntu. Maybe in the future it would be easier when phones will be more generic.